# close a browser by providing tear down only in robotframework

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

```
*** Settings ***

*** Test Cases ***
Browser Shutdown

*** Keywords ***
Browser Shutdown
    Close Browser
```

file closebrowser.txt contains no keyword error shown when run this file.
I just want to execute this file at the end of all test cases so that if browser is open this will close that

in closebrowser.txt i dont want to execute any test, only tear down the browser(s) after executing all the test.txt file in the folder. Since i can add one or more test file in the folder (e.g. test3.txt,test4.txt...) so instead of providing in these file i want a separate file which will run and close the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create _*init*_.txt file to each of the directories and add

```
*** Settings ***
Suite teardown    Close all browsers
```

to the file. That will add suite teardown that will be run after any test suites in the directory. The _*init*_.txt is called an initialization file

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a `Test Case` in another `Test Case`.

You've three way to define `TearDown`

```
*** Settings ***
Test Teardown     Close All Browsers
Suite Teardown     Close All Browsers

*** Test Cases ***
My Test
    ...
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
```

`Test Teardown` and `[Teardown]` will be executed at the end of a every Test Case inside a Suite, `Suite Teardown` only at the end of the Suite.

Comment: First of all in `closebrowser.txt` you can remove the `*** Test Cases ***` section and it become a `resource`. As you can read here (http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.6.2#test-setup-and-teardown) is not possible execute a "default" file.

Comment: It is possible execute a teardown at the end of a test or at the of a suite.